# Quadratic integer equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I am trying to find integer solutions to
$\space 2x^2-y^2=1\space $ other than $\space (1,1).\quad$ Just one is sufficient, and I know (by brute force) that
$\space (5,7)\space $ is one. How do I show my work?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's a tutorial of [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See [Pell's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)

Comment: As the comment of @lulu indicates, your equation is equivalent to the equation $X^2 - Dy^2 = \pm 1 ~: ~X,Y,D \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~D ~$ is **square free**.  Here, you are specifically interested only in the solutions where the RHS is $-1$, rather than $+1$.  So, (for example) $(X,Y) = (1,1)$ is good, while $(X,Y) = (3,2)$ is not.  For further reading, see [this pdf file](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf) and [this one](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf).  ...See next comment.

Comment: In the previous comment, for the first pdf file linked to, you might wish to only focus on chapter 1, depending on your interests.  The study of Pell's equation is wrapped in the study of Continued Fractions.  **Warning**: in my opinion, the (overall) study of Pell's equation is a somewhat advanced subtopic of Number Theory. ...see next comment.

Comment: For what it's worth, **all** solutions to $X^2 - 2Y^2 = -1$ (rather than $+1$) are given by $(X,Y) = (P_k, Q_k)$, where $(P_k + Q_k\sqrt{2}) = (1 + \sqrt{2})^k ~: ~k~$ is an **odd** positive integer.

Comment: It can be shown that given an ordered pair of solutions, a new ordered pair can be found where each member is a linear combination of the previous solutions. The same linear transform is then applicable to this solution. In other words, you can use matrix multiplication to generate a solution. Diagonalizing the matrix helps yield a formula for solutions as a function of n.

Comment: "How do I show my work?" Plug in $5, 7$ for $x,y$ and see that the result is $1$. Nothing more.

Comment: @Max Bow-Arrow  Please look at my updated answer. I think I have found a way to find all integer solutions and to generate the $\space n^{th}\space$ one directly.

Answer (score 0):

A "Y-solution" and a spreadsheet show a lot. It is semi-brute force but not hard.  Make an $\space x$-column with sequential numbers where $\quad n\le x \le 1000+x.\quad$ in the next column put the formula from the RHS of "y=". In the next column over enter
$\quad\text{IF(Y-value=INT(Y-value),"***","").}\quad$ In the top row of this column use "COUNTIF()" to count the number of asterisks down to the thousandth row. If the count is greater than zero, search the rows below for integers. Change the first number in the $\space x$-column up by $1000$ to continue counting 1000 at a time.

\begin{align*}
2x^2-y^2&=1\\ 
\implies 2x^2 y^2 - 1 &= y^2\\
\implies y=\pm&\sqrt{2
x^2-1}\\
\implies (x,y)\in\pm& 
\big\{(1,1),(5,7),(29,41),(169,239),(985,1393),\cdots\big\}
\end{align*}

$\textbf{Update: }\space $ I just noticed a pattern in this series.
All $\space x$-values can be generated by the following formula which generates every other
[Pell Number](https://oeis.org/A000129)
which means that the $\space n^{th}\space x\space$  can be generated directly.

$$ 
 x= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{(2n-1)} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{(2n-1)}}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: Re my last comment following the original question, is your approach easier/better than computing $$\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right)^k ~: ~k ~~\text{is an odd positive integer?}$$

Comment: @user2661923   I have  not explored your formula though it may have merit. This is because I found a better solution explained in my update.

Comment: @user2661923 Update. I tried your formula using odd integers and it did not generate integers until  $\space k \ge 15\space$ and then it generated only even numbers. Perhaps I read you formula wrong.

Comment: $$\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right)^2 = \left(3 + 2\sqrt{2}\right) ~~\text{and}~~ 3^2 - 2(2)^2 = (-1)^2.$$ $$\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right)^3 = \left(7 + 5\sqrt{2}\right) ~~\text{and}~~ 7^2 - 2(5)^2 = (-1)^3.$$